# Problems installing on Lenovo ideapad 100s-11iby

Tags: boot, uefi, lenovo, ideapad

I recently bought a Lenovo 100s as a lightweight, portable, cheap pc. First step was to clean it and install Ubuntu but I've run into some problems. Firstly they have installed 32 bit Windows and a 32 bit EFI on the machine even though it has 64 bit architecture. The EFI also has no legacy support, so I need a 32 bit ubuntu with EFI support (although I want 64 bit since the hardware supports it). PC has no dvd drive or LAN port, so those boot options are not possible. Anyone have any ideas? I'm a bit of a linux scrub so a step by step would be much appreciated if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have another computer to make a LiveUSB on?

Comment: Well, it seem to be possible to load 64 bit OS Linux from a 32 bit UEFI. I found [this technical blog post](http://vzimmer.blogspot.ru/2013/02/32-versus-64-bit-and-measuring-uefi.html) about the idiosyncrasies of 32/64 bit UEFI/OS, and [this patch](https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/3/4/242), dated by 2014, enabling a possibility to load 64 bit Linux kernel from a 32 bit UEFI.

Comment: Okay, after a bit of diving into the theme, I'd advice you to just try 64 bit Ubuntu, it would probably work with disregard to EFI32. [There was a blog post](https://blog.einval.com/2015/08/02#intel_justifies_mixed_efi) about adding so called mixed mode *(to load 64 bit systems from 32 bit UEFI)* into Debian *(I'm absolutely don't recommend Debian as opposed to *buntu for a number of reasons — that's just an example)*.

Answer (score 1):

I also have a Lenovo Thinkpad 100 (not sure about the 's') and previously replaced the Win10 OS with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit (I've just upgraded to 16.04). I created a bootable USB using [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) and booted from that (using the weird concealed boot button next to the headphone socket - I use an unfolded paperclip).

Hope that helps.

Comment: It doesn't work with Lenovo Ideapad 100s 11iby.